# Binding List of data to several DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have data in ViewModel which I bind to DataGrid. But I need multiple data and bind that dynamically to several DataGrids.

```
public sealed class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataTable data;
    public DataTable Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; OnPropertyChanged("Data"); }
    }

    private char[] head;
    public char[] Head
    {
        get { return head; }
        set { head = value; OnPropertyChanged("Head"); }
    }

    private char name;
    public char Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private static readonly ViewModel instance = new ViewModel();

    public static ViewModel Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    } 
    private ViewModel()
    {
        data = new DataTable();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

My DataGrid in XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgOutput" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Data, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" HeadersVisibility="All">
  <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="Row header" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Name}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

I have an idea like this: to have any collection and each item to bind to one DataGrid. I don't know how much items will be in the collection, of course.

```
List<Data> list = new List<Data>;
list.Add(new Data(dataTable, head, name);
list.Add(new Data(dataTable, head, name);

list[0]; //bind to first DataGrid
list[1]; //bind to second DataGrid
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding your data table to data grid, try binding it to data view.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataView view = table.DefaultView;
```

View Model will contain list of tables and something like:

```
dataGrid[0].ItemSource = table[0].DefaultView;
dataGrid[1].ItemSource = table[1].DefaultView;
```

The above could also be moved to xaml.

Now hopefully this solves property changed notification works as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I need to bind my properties like Data, Head and Name to one DataGrid. And I also don't know how to bind my Head property to rows header of DataGrid.

Comment: I solve it with use the Caliburn.Micro framework and his Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive